# Generate Figure Wide Axes for Figure with Multiple Plots (grid)

Tags: r

I have an analysis in which I varying parameters of a model, and would like to generate a well-labeled figure showing the effects of various combinations of settings.  I can generate the actual plots without issue, and arrange them in a grid.  Now I would like to add axes which refer not to the data but to the parameter values that I am varying.  Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do.

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)

dat <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

# these are my parameters
scales <- c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 10, 15)
adds <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# generate data to be plotted
revData <- list()
ptr <- 1
for (ii in 1:length(scales)){
    for (jj in 1:length(adds)){
        revData[[ptr]] <- (dat * scales[[ii]]) + adds[[jj]]
        ptr <- ptr + 1
    }
}

# generating plots
plotList <- lapply(revData, function(xx){
    xyplot(xx ~ 1:1000)
})
names(plotList) <- sprintf("N%s", 1:length(plotList))
plotList <- c(plotList, list(ncol=length(scales)))
do.call(grid.arrange, plotList)
```

This produces the following figure:
[image]

What I would like to do now is generate X and Y axes for this set of plots, in which the X-axis refers to the `scales` variable and has the values listed, and similarly a Y-axis which corresponds to the `adds` value.  How do I do this?

Comment: How about using the `sub` and `left` arguments of `grid.arrange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer using `grid` package. First create a grid of viewports, then at each iteration of creating the data just plot it. This maybe gives a bit more control over spacing.

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)

# Data
dat <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

# these are my parameters
scales <- c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 10, 15)
adds <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Create grid layout - this lets you look at the plot grid: 6 by 6 with the first column and last row used for the additional parameter labels.

```
grid.show.layout(grid.layout(6, 6, 
                   widths = unit(c(2, rep(1,5)), c("lines", rep("null",5))) ,
                   heights = unit(c(rep(1,5),2), c(rep("null",5), "lines"))))
```

Start plot

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(6, 6, 
                       widths = unit(c(2, rep(1,5)), c("lines", rep("null",5))) ,
                       heights = unit(c(rep(1,5),2), c(rep("null",5), "lines")))))

# generate data and plot
for (ii in 1:length(scales)) {

      for (jj in 1:length(adds)) {

           revData <- (dat * scales[ii]) + adds[jj]

           # plot (top to bottom / left to right)
           pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=jj, layout.pos.col=ii+1))
           plot(xyplot(revData ~ 1:1000 , xlab=NULL , ylab=NULL) , newpage=FALSE)
           upViewport(1)
       }
    }
```

add "scales" labels to x-axis

```
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=6, layout.pos.col=2:6 ))
grid.text(scales, x=seq(0.1,0.9 ,length=5), y=0.8 , hjust=0.2, 
                            gp=gpar(col="red" , fontsize=14))
grid.text("Scales" , x=0.5 , y=0.3 ,  gp=gpar(fontsize=20)) 
grid.lines(y=1 , gp=gpar(col="red"))
upViewport(1)
```

add "adds" labels to y-axis

```
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1:5, layout.pos.col=1 ))
grid.text(rev(adds),hjust=0.4 , x=0.8, y=seq(0.1,0.9 ,length=5), rot=90, 
                           gp=gpar(col="red" , fontsize=14))
grid.text("Adds" , x=0.3 , y=0.5 ,  rot=90, gp=gpar(fontsize=20)) 
grid.lines(x=1 , gp=gpar(col="red"))
```

**EDIT**

I added axis titles using `grid.text` and tweaking the x & y slightly. A better way would be to add another row and column to the grid and use this for the labels. An example grid is below - you will need to tweak another couple of things in the code but is not difficult.

```
grid.show.layout(grid.layout(7,7,
       widths = unit(c(2, 2,rep(1,5)), c("lines", "lines",rep("null",5))) ,
       heights = unit(c(rep(1,5),2,2), c(rep("null",5), "lines","lines"))))
```

You could use the first column and last row for axis titles, the second column and second last row for axis labels and line, leaving the rest of the grid for the plot.

[image]

Comment: That's almost perfect - is there any way I can also label these axes (i.e. `scales`)?  If not, that's OK.  But this is basically what I was trying to do :)

Comment: @learner; your very welcome. Have alook at https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/grid/grid.html for lots of info on the grid package

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can add a `textGrob` underneath and to the left of the plot to indicate what value of "scales" or "adds" each plot represents. The `sub` and `left` arguments of `grid.arrange` can be used.

```
do.call(grid.arrange, 
        c(plotList , 
        list(
        sub = textGrob(paste0("scales_",scales), 
                       x=unit(seq(0.05,0.85,length=5), "npc"), 
                       hjust=0, vjust=0 , 
                       gp=gpar(col="red", fontsize=14) ),        
        left = textGrob(paste0("adds_",rev(adds)), 
                        y=unit(seq(0.05,0.85,length=5), "npc"), 
                        hjust=0, vjust=1 , rot = 90, 
                        gp=gpar(col="red", fontsize=14) ))))
```

You will need to play about with the x and y coordinates.

This produces the plot:

[image]